# Is there any way to convert specific JSON data to CSV?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have JSON format which looks like

Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RqU2s0dqjd60dcYlxEJ8vnw9_z2fWixd/view?usp=sharing

```
result =

{
      "ERROR":[
         
      ],
      "LinkSetDbHistory":[
         
      ],
      "LinkSetDb":[
         {
            "Link":[
               {
                  "Id":"8116078"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"7654180"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"7643601"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"7017037"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"6190213"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"5902265"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"5441934"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"5417587"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"5370323"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"5362514"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"4818642"
               },
               {
                  "Id":"4330602"
               }
            ],
            "DbTo":"pmc",
            "LinkName":"pubmed_pmc_refs"
         }
      ],
      "DbFrom":"pubmed",
      "IdList":[
         "25209241"
      ]
   },




{
      "ERROR":[
   ],
  "LinkSetDbHistory":[
     
  ],
  "LinkSetDb":[
     {
        "Link":[
           {
              "Id":"7874507"
           },
           {
              "Id":"7378719"
           },
           {
              "Id":"6719480"
           },
           {
              "Id":"5952809"
           },
           {
              "Id":"4944516"
           }
        ],
        "DbTo":"pmc",
        "LinkName":"pubmed_pmc_refs"
     }
  ],
  "DbFrom":"pubmed",
  "IdList":[
     "25209630"
  ]
```

},

I want to fetch ID with a length which is 12 and list

```
"IdList":"25209241"
```

so the final output will be

```
IDList: length

25209241: 12 (Total number of Id in link array)
25209630 : 5 (Total number of Id in link array)
```

I have tried this code but not working with single or multiple values.

```
pmc_ids = [link["Id"] for link in results["LinkSetDb"]["Link"]]
len(pmc_ids)
```

How it can work with a large dataset if there?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. For one thing, the final output doesn't look like CSV format. What exactly in the JSON data is being sought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Link' key is inside a list. So, change `pmc_ids = [link["Id"] for link in results["LinkSetDb"]["Link"]]` to `pmc_ids = [link["Id"] for link in results["LinkSetDb"][0]["Link"]]`.

To generate csv file, the code would be something like this:

```py
import json
import csv

with open('Citation_with_ID.json', 'r') as f_json:
    json_data = f_json.read()
f_json.close()

json_dict = json.loads(json_data)

csv_headers = ["IdList", "length"]
csv_values = []
for i in json_dict:
    if len(i["LinkSetDb"])>0:
        pmc_ids = [link["Id"] for link in i["LinkSetDb"][0]["Link"]]
    else:
        pmc_ids = []
    length = len(pmc_ids)
    if len(i['IdList'])==1:
        IdList = i['IdList'][0]
    else:
        IdList = None
    csv_values.append([IdList,length])

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f_csv:
    w = csv.writer(f_csv)
    w.writerow(csv_headers)
    w.writerows(csv_values)
f_csv.close()
```

If you want to store the values in a dictionary then something like this can be used:

```py
values_list = list(zip(*csv_values))
dict(zip(values_list[0],values_list[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `"LinkSetDb"` as a list containing a single dictionary but you are indexing it as if it is a dictionary. Use:

```
pmc_ids = [link["Id"] for link in result["LinkSetDb"][0]["Link"]]
len(pmc_ids)
```